# Insert DateTime into BigQuery in Stream

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I am trying to insert data into a datetime field in BigQuery via WriteStream in Java and keep getting the error

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot return an invalid datetime value of 1639484762470 microseconds relative to the Unix epoch. The range of valid datetime values is [0001-01-01 00:00:00, 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999999] on field date_time.
```

I tried different options: seconds, milliseconds, microseconds, cast from Unix format to Microsoft, insert formatted string (then I get an error that it should be INT64).

Where am I going wrong?

Code is pretty simple

```
try (JsonStreamWriter writer = JsonStreamWriter.newBuilder(writeStream.getName(), writeStream.getTableSchema(), client).build()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            JSONObject record = new JSONObject();
            Date date = new Date();
            record.put("date_hash", date.hashCode());
            record.put("date_string", date.toString());
            record.put("date_time", date.getTime());
            jsonArr.put(record);
        }
        
        ApiFuture<AppendRowsResponse> future = writer.append(jsonArr, i * 10);
        AppendRowsResponse response = future.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have this value interpreted as **_microseconds_** on server side, which must be wrong (and below the lower bound of the valid **milliseconds** from 1970-01-01... See the error message at `…1639484762470 microseconds…`, the value is a valid unix time when interpreted as milliseconds.

Comment: If you can use `java.time` (Java 8+), consider using that. The way with `Date` and `Calendar` is outdated.

Comment: Some result was obtained with
3 899 232 054 000 000 000
it
(((((2021L * 12) + 11) * 31 + 13) * 24 + 16) * 60 + 15) * 60 * 1000 * 1000);
But for some reason in the database it is displayed as
0923-08-12T03: 52: 09.485632